# Firebase cloud messaging (FCM) server key option in connect cube showing error

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, connectycube

I want to implement push  notification in my react native app. for that I have created project on firebase.
Now I as per the ConnectyCube documents I need to set server key from that firebase account but it is not setting that key it is showing error of 'remove API key'.

If it is wrong then which key should I set?

Comment: Yes I am also facing same issue. And my work is stuck because of that I need help from connect cube as soon as possible.

Comment: I was able to successfully put Firebase Server key (a new one, which is longer than an old legacy) and all is ok, Please post here your error, screenshot

Answer (score 0):

[This server key I am setting for FCM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxUQb.jpg)

[ConnectyCube FCM screen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtogd.jpg)